# React login page (client side) and spring boot/security (server side)

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

Has anybody any hint how to make the authentication on server side (java spring boot) and login page with react on client side? I mean I know less more how the spring security works, but I do not use the client side rendering, I am using the API which I created with separated app in java. 
Then I created the login page in react and I wonder how to deal with the logging on client side...

Has anybody some articles?

I searched in google, but most of the examples are weard or just do not include the client -> server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using JWT (JSON Web Tokens). What happens is when a user logs in the server sends a JWT token to the client. This token is set to the header of each request from then on. Any request to the server without this token would be rejected. JWTs can be implemented with spring security. When you search for Spring JWT on your web browser the first few links will help you on implementing it.

To set the authorization header I'd suggest using a package like axios on your React front end.

Comment: Sure I use the axios :). The only concern I had, what approach should I follow. Thanks for feedback, I have to dig in this security staff.